# Expression for Yes/No/Unclear(?) in medical score-based diagnosis

Tags: expressions, medical

This is a repost of a question in CrossValidated which received no attention.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169085/yes-no-unclear-count-score-based-decision-quest-for-terminology

In medical research, scores are often used to assess the severeness of symptoms, and thresholds for pathological/normal are defined. For example, when a score from a questionnaire is 81, and the threshold is 80, this is considered a pathological finding.

I would like to point out that such a threshold is artificial, and that a green/yellow/red system can be more useful. So scores above 90 would be considered "most likely pathological", scores below 50 "most likely normal", and the yellow zone in-between would be "no decision, look for other criteria".

To explain the concept to physicians, what would be a good name for the middle range? "Indifference"? "Uncertainty"? "Undecided"?

So how would you complete the sentence:

"Scores between 50 and 90 are in the xxx-zone; for these patients, please consider additional criteria for diagnose".

Comment: I can't resist 'grey area' :)

Comment: Not bad. Similar to "yellow", but less traffic-light bound.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest saying that scores in the intermediate range are **inconclusive** because the result is **ambiguous**, or some permutation of such words.

Answer (score 1):

*Inconclusive zone* is nice, but a little hard to pronounce (for native English speakers, too) I think.

**unclear zone**

OR

**questionable zone**

---

Edit: **indeterminate [zone]**

Comment: "questionable" has a bit of a moral undertone for me.

Comment: @DieterMenne - Good to know.  That helped me come up with one more: **indeterminate** or indeterminate zone.

Comment: Good choice. The opposite is determinate, which is (rightfully) less than "certain".

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

**Equivocal zone**

- Equivocal : *allowing the possibility of several different meanings,  of doubtful nature or character, of uncertain significance, questionable, ambiguous, dubious; not determined*.

or, more usual:

**area of uncertainty**.

Comment: My medical colleague also favored variants of "uncertainty", but as a statistician, I don't like it. For us, everything is uncertain, more or less so, and there is a danger that uncertain implieds certainty outside. The famous statistician's comment when seeing a Friesian cow on the meadow: "From this side, it looks like a cow".

Comment: @DieterMenne - I would then say that *Scores between 50 and 90 are non-conclusive* (a variant of "inconclusive" mentionned by apparente001).